# How do I get bootstrap-datepicker to work with Bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I use the version of [bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker) maintained by [eternicode](https://github.com/eternicode) (Andrew Rowls).

On Bootstrap 2 it worked, but now it doesn't work with the Bootstrap 3 library.

How can I get [bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker) to work with `Bootstrap 3`?

**Note:** The repository moved from [eternicode](https://github.com/eternicode) to an organization account (uxsolutions).

Comment: Isnt eternicode supporting bootstrap 3

Comment: Yes it is just a dumb selector mistake on my side.

Comment: Eternicode now supports Bootstrap 3: https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/426

Comment: Great question - I completely disagree that this should be closed, as it discusses an issue in depth that we have with migrating to Bootstrap 3.

Comment: Ok, this is ready to reopen if we flag it. It can no longer be called off-topic. Right?

Comment: @digitalextremist: unlikely.  The resolution to this question is found in the comments.  If this question were reopened it would be closed again as being a typo.

Answer (score 84):

I also use Stefan Petre’s http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker and it does not work with Bootstrap 3 without modification.  Note that http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/ is a fork of Stefan Petre's code.

You have to change your markup (the sample markup will not work) to use the new CSS and form grid layout in Bootstrap 3.  Also, you have to modify some CSS and JavaScript in the actual bootstrap-datepicker implementation.

Here is my solution:

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-xs-8">
    <label class="control-label">My Label</label>
    <div class="input-group date" id="dp3" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" readonly="" value="12-02-2012">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS changes in datepicker.css on lines 176-177:

```
.input-group.date .input-group-addon i,
.input-group.date .input-group-addon i {
```

Javascript change in datepicker-bootstrap.js on line 34:

```
this.component = this.element.is('.date') ? this.element.find('.input-group-addon') : false;
```

**UPDATE**

Using the newer code from http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/ the changes are as follows:

CSS changes in datepicker.css on lines 446-447:

```
.input-group.date .input-group-addon i,
.input-group.date .input-group-addon i {
```

Javascript change in datepicker-bootstrap.js on line 46:

```
 this.component = this.element.is('.date') ? this.element.find('.input-group-addon, .btn') : false;
```

Finally, the JavaScript to enable the datepicker (with some options):

```
 $(".input-group.date").datepicker({ autoclose: true, todayHighlight: true });
```

Tested with Bootstrap 3.0 and JQuery 1.9.1.  Note that this fork is better to use than the other as it is more feature rich, has localization support and auto-positions the datepicker based on the control position and window size, avoiding the picker going off the screen which was a problem with the older version.

Comment: The JavaScript change in the http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/ 's `datepicker-bootstrap.js` is not on `line 46` it is on `line 44`. Just thought to let you know as I noticed it when I downloaded and edited it today. Thanks for this... it works great `:)`

Comment: Thanks, this works great! Now if only I can figure out how to get it working in the modal popup with BS 3...

Comment: The newest version of this site now works with bootstrap 3
http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox

Comment: @Justin ... I had problems with this working in BS 3 modal as well. It turns out the calendar was opening, but it was opening behind the modal. The modal was large enough to hide the calendar. In bootstrap-datepicker.js I edited line 552, and instead of adding 10 to the z-index, I added 9999, et viola, the calendar appeared.

'code'
var zIndex = parseInt(this.element.parents().filter(function(){
     return $(this).css('z-index') !== 'auto';
    }).first().css('z-index'))+9999;

Comment: There are 2 css files, datepicker.css and datepicker3.css, which one is used?

Comment: I made all my changes in datepicker.css

Answer (score 22):

For anyone else who runs into this...

Version 1.2.0 of this plugin (current as of this post) doesn't quite work in all cases as documented with Bootstrap 3.0, but it does with a minor workaround.

Specifically, if using an input with icon, the HTML markup is of course slightly different as class names have changed:

```
<div class="input-group" data-datepicker="true">
    <input name="date" type="text" class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
```

It seems because of this, you need to use a selector that points directly to the input element itself **NOT** the parent container (which is what the auto generated HTML on the demo page suggests).

```
$('*[data-datepicker="true"] input[type="text"]').datepicker({
    todayBtn: true,
    orientation: "top left",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
});
```

Having done this you will probably also want to add a listener for clicking/tapping on the icon so it sets focus on the text input when clicked (which is the behaviour when using this plugin with TB 2.x by default).

```
$(document).on('touch click', '*[data-datepicker="true"] .input-group-addon', function(e){
    $('input[type="text"]', $(this).parent()).focus();
});
```

NB: I just use a data-datepicker boolean attribute because the class name 'datepicker' is reserved by the plugin and I already use 'date' for styling elements.

Comment: thanks much @Iain  I was frustrated especially by the fact that icon would not respond.  very helpful